# write linq query sitemapnode

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, telerik

I want to write query `smn.ParentNode.ChildNodes`.  If ShowInNavigation value false, I don't want to show. Telerik Site map node has this att. Ho to do this?

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Web;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;

public partial class CustomTemplate_Navigation : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        SiteMapNode smn = SiteMapBase.GetCurrentProvider().CurrentNode;

        while (smn.ParentNode != null)
        {
            if (smn.ParentNode.ParentNode == SiteMap.RootNode)
            {               
                siteMapControl_verticaltree.DataSource = smn.ParentNode.ChildNodes;/*this line will be write query*/
                siteMapControl_verticaltree.DataBind();
                break;
            }

            smn = smn.ParentNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ChildNodes a property of ParentNode. Why do you want to write that in query?

Comment: to visible some node which is showInNavigation node's value false.

Comment: Can you tell us what's the type of ChildNodes

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
smn.ParentNode.ChildNodes.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.ShowInNavigation).ToList();
```

Comment: Error 11 'System.Web.SiteMapNodeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.SiteMapNodeCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @temp - You have to Linqify it with `AsQuerable()` as I show above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do somthing like this: (you should not only Linqify, but you need a cast also) 
(I used this in a .NET MVC4 project)

```
SiteMapNodeCollection coll = SiteMap.RootNode.ChildNodes;
IEnumerable<SiteMapNode> nodes = coll.Cast<SiteMapNode>();
var query = from node in nodes where Boolean.Parse(node["ShowInNavigation"]) == true select node;
```